# AWS Canary Selenium User Agent String

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium, amazon-cloudwatch

I am looking to set a custom user agent in AWS Selenium Canary, but somehow what I am trying to do is not working

According to this documentation I should be able to change/append a string to the browser's user agent header...

```
add_user_agent(user_agent_str)
Appends the value of user_agent_str to the browser's user agent header. You must assign user_agent_str before creating the browser instance.

Example:

synthetics_webdriver.add_user_agent('MyApp-1.0')
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Synthetics_Canaries_Library_Python.html

This is my sample code

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import selenium.common.exceptions
from aws_synthetics.selenium import synthetics_webdriver
from aws_synthetics.common import synthetics_logger as logger
from aws_synthetics.common import synthetics_configuration


async def main():
    synthetics_configuration.set_config(
        {
            "screenshot_on_step_start": False,
            "screenshot_on_step_success": True,
            "screenshot_on_step_failure": True
        }
    )

    synthetics_webdriver.add_user_agent('My User Agent String')
    driver = synthetics_webdriver.Chrome()
        
    driver.get('myurl.com')
    user_agent = driver.execute_script('return navigator.userAgent')
    # should be/contain 'My User Agent String' but instead looks like 'CloudWatchSynthetics-arn'
    logger.info('This is the user agent string: {}'.format(user_agent))
    
    # selenium python tests

async def handler(event, context):
   return await main()
```

I've done a lot of debugging, making sure the method exists, moving the method to the top of a file, but I haven't had any luck getting it to work

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, you need to create an object first to execute the `add_user_agent` method and save that state.

I don't have the environment so please try this and let me know the result in the comment.

```py
    syn_wdriver = synthetics_webdriver
    # syn_wdriver = synthetics_webdriver() # try this one if above does not work, i'm not sure about the syn_webdriver object
    syn_wdriver.add_user_agent('My User Agent String')
    driver = syn_wdriver.Chrome()
```

Or:

```py
    driver = synthetics_webdriver.add_user_agent('My User Agent String').Chrome()
```

Answer (score 0):

I just dove into my own code again and realize I was making a simple mistake

this was my structure

```
def myfunction():
    # my selenium test

myfunction()
```

However, when I did this, the add_user_agent function for some reason does not inject the browser user agent header with the string

when i changed the code to this

```
def myfunction():
    # selenium tests
webdriver.execute_step('StepName', myfunction)
```

it worked just fine...